# Exclude passwords with repeating letters

Tags: passwords, brute-force, hydra

It would cut down a lot of time of the brute force attack if some of those passwords like "aaaaaa" wouldn't appear. How can this be achieved in Hydra or some other brute force software?

Comment: How do you know the password isn't "aaaaaa"?

Comment: Good question, can't really answer that xD . But it would help me a lot if those kind of passwords would not appear.

Comment: You could optimize your check by only checking "aaaaaa", without losing any completeness guarantees. Could you please explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Just generate a wordlist with a higher-level scripting language. Besides that, `aaaaaa` is not an uncommon password and excluding repeating letters would probably not save you a lot of time.

Comment: Client-side validation would be handy for this. *How* to do it is your own coding challenge (and off-topic here)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fair to say that 5 truly random letters are going to be less likely than 5 repeated letters, even if "aaaaa", isn't practical to type...the people who make these passwords have avoided much practical thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Hydra i'm assuming you're on Kali Linux, so 'crunch' should be installed. In which case, you could do something similar to this to generate your wordlist (1 to 10 character alphanumeric):
`crunch 1 10 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 | grep -Ev '(.)\1'`
This may eat up a fair amount of hard disk space though.